# WHy this error occur in laravel unique validator

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-6

child has same `child_birth_certificate_no` with another child, it is fine. but the same centre cannot

so, it must only fail when the `child_birth_certificate_no` is same as another child IN THE SAME CENTRE

The error that I am facing is:

```
message: "Class App\Http\Requests\Child\Request does not exist"
exception: "ReflectionException"
```

My code

```
public function rules(Request $request) {
$this->validate($request,array(
            'child_birth_certificate_no' =>'required|unique:tbl_child,child_birth_certificate_no',
            'centre_id'=> 'required|unique:tbl_child,centre_id',
        ));

        return $to_validate;

    }
```

Comment: can you also include all the namespace and using statement for the `rules(Request $request)` file

Comment: sorry, i didn't get it.Can you tell me detail?

Comment: I think you forget import `Class App\Http\Requests\Child\Request` in controller or forget create it

Answer (score 0):

If that is the `rules` in your custom [`Request`][1]; let's call it `Child`

[1]: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#creating-form-requests then remove `Request $request` and try the following:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'child_birth_certificate_no' =>'required|unique:tbl_child,child_birth_certificate_no',
        'centre_id'=> 'required|unique:tbl_child,centre_id',
    ];
}
```

Then use it in your controller with a variation of the following:

```
<?php
...

use App\Http\Requests\Child;

...


public function store(Child $request)
{
    // The incoming request is valid...

    // Retrieve the validated input data...
    $validated = $request->validated();

    ...
}
```